# Correct method of using Material theme in Lollipop and pre-Lollipop

Tags: android, material-design

If we want to support both Lollipop and pre-Lollipop devices for an app with Material design which among the following is the right method ?

1. Use Android Support Library alone: Use only support library for the whole app and don't use any of the API 21. I have tested this and it works in emulator. I could get the material features in a Lollipop device in emulator.
2. Use both API 21 and Android Support Library simultaneously in the App: Provide alternative styles, alternative layouts etc... one using API 21 and other one using Android Support Library as mentioned in Android's [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html).

My confusion is, if I am going with option 1, is it the right approach for Lollipop devices ? Will that be lesser memory efficient ?

Otherwise if I am going with option 2, will it be an overkill if that is not actually required ?

Also in 2nd option, for using Toolbar, we can have alternative layouts in two folders (layouts and layouts-v21) with layout in first folder using `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` and layout in second folder using `Toolbar`.
But to have it set as `ActionBar` it is sufficient for Lollipop to have the activity to inherit from `Activity` class. But pre-Lollipop will need to inherit from `ActionBarActivity`. So will we need to have two activity files too ?

Please point out if I have blurted out any blunders.

Comment: For newest material design integration visit www.takeoffandroid.com

Answer (score 0):

Some features are only available in v21 like riplle effect, so if you want to use ripple effect in your app than use both support library for back support and v21 for lollipop.
Use custom XML/Java for pre lollipop, for lollipop just add your animation/design in v21 folders

Comment: Just to confirm, If I don't want any feature that is not available in Support Library in a particular Activity, but requires certain feature like RecyclerView or Toolbar, do I have to use just Support Library ? Will it be as memory efficient for Lollipop devices as it is while using original Toolbar or RecyclerView API from API 21 ?

Comment: You can use both RecylerView and Toolbar in pre lollipop like KitKat or below, but lollipop provides certain features which are only available in lollipop like ripple effect, radius, shadow, if you want to use them in pre lollipop use your own created drawables but for v21 aka lollipop use default

Comment: Highly recommend to use support library, consider in future you want to use some features which are only available in lollipop or latest version milkshake than what you will do, code again to change everything? If you are using Fragments than its recommend to use support library

Comment: I don't think I could convey quite well my exact doubt to you. It is not when to use support library and when to use API 21. My scenario is that in my app I need to use only those widgets that are available in Support Library. Also my project targets Lollipop and pre-L devices. What is a better approach for L devices ? To use API 21 widgets or to go for Support Library widgets ? I know that Support library WILL work. (If we build entirely using Support Library, we will have lesser code to deal with also. ) But is that a good approach ? as far as memory and performance is considered